How to ignore SSL errors in embedded Chromium browser when using jcefmaven
I am using a demo app from https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefsampleapp
When I am loading localhost with an invalid certificate I get the error:
Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" [0405/134130.277708:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(874)] CertVerifyProcBuiltin for localhost failed:
----- Certificate i=2 (CN=root) -----
ERROR: No matching issuer found


[0405/134130.278498:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(970)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202


Does someone know how to ignore SSL certificates?

To fix this error you need to implement RequestHandler and add logic to a onCertificateError
Here is an example

in MainFrame you have to add:

client_.addRequestHandler(new RequestHandler(this));


Add RequestHandler

import org.cef.browser.CefBrowser;
import org.cef.browser.CefFrame;
import org.cef.callback.CefAuthCallback;
import org.cef.callback.CefCallback;
import org.cef.handler.CefLoadHandler.ErrorCode;
import org.cef.handler.CefRequestHandler;
import org.cef.handler.CefResourceRequestHandler;
import org.cef.handler.CefResourceRequestHandlerAdapter;
import org.cef.misc.BoolRef;
import org.cef.network.CefRequest;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class RequestHandler extends CefResourceRequestHandlerAdapter implements CefRequestHandler {
    private final Frame owner_;

    public RequestHandler(Frame owner) {
        owner_ = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBeforeBrowse(CefBrowser cefBrowser, CefFrame cefFrame, CefRequest cefRequest, boolean b, boolean b1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOpenURLFromTab(CefBrowser cefBrowser, CefFrame cefFrame, String s, boolean b) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public CefResourceRequestHandler getResourceRequestHandler(CefBrowser cefBrowser, CefFrame cefFrame, CefRequest cefRequest, boolean b, boolean b1, String s, BoolRef boolRef) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getAuthCredentials(CefBrowser cefBrowser, String s, boolean b, String s1, int i, String s2, String s3, CefAuthCallback cefAuthCallback) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCertificateError(CefBrowser browser, ErrorCode cert_error, String request_url, CefCallback callback) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CertErrorDialog(owner_, cert_error, request_url, callback));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenderProcessTerminated(CefBrowser cefBrowser, TerminationStatus terminationStatus) {

    }
}


And CertErrorDialog

import org.cef.callback.CefCallback;
import org.cef.handler.CefLoadHandler.ErrorCode;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CertErrorDialog implements Runnable {
    private final Frame owner_;
    private final ErrorCode cert_error_;
    private final String request_url_;
    private final CefCallback callback_;

    public CertErrorDialog(
            Frame owner, ErrorCode cert_error, String request_url, CefCallback callback) {
        owner_ = owner;
        cert_error_ = cert_error;
        request_url_ = request_url;
        callback_ = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(owner_,
                "An certificate error (" + cert_error_ + ") occurreed "
                        + "while requesting\n" + request_url_ + "\nDo you want to proceed anyway?",
                "Certificate error", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        if (dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            callback_.Continue();
        } else {
            callback_.cancel();
        }
    }
}

Sample code could be found in https://github.com/jcefmaven/jcefmaven/blob/9c28d0480f3c232719d86728d61a4c67516c0f3a/jcefmaven/src/test/java/me/friwi/jcefmaven/detailed/handler/RequestHandler.java#L30
